# Exercise on composition of Poisson processes

Tags: probability, poisson-process

This is a practice exercise on Poisson processes (not homework).
Suppose that cars and trucks move between destinations A and B. Their movement can be described as two independent Poisson processes with respective rates 4 cars and 3 trucks per minute.

1) What is the probability that a person who started hitchhiking at 17:30 will first encounter a car?

2) What is the probability that the first three vehicles consist of two cars and one truck?

3) What is the probability that between 17:35-17:40 a person will encounter 3 cars and 2 trucks?

I know that the question is on composition of independent Poisson processes. However, I am not sure how I should approach solving the exercise, especially 1) and 2). Also, I am a bot confused when I should use joint probability and conditional probability for Poisson processes. In other words, when $P\{N(t)=1 | N_{1}(t)=1 \}$ vs $P\{N(t)=1,N_{1}(t)=1 \}$ where $N(t)=N_{1}(t)=1 + N_{2}(t)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) What is the probability that a person who started hitchhiking at 17:30 will first encounter a car?
>
> 2) What is the probability that the first three vehicles consist of two cars and one truck?

Vehicles are arriving in two independent Poisson processes at rates of 4 cars and 3 trucks per minute.

Then the vehicles are arriving in a Poisson process with a rate of seven vehicles per minute, where each arrival has an independent probability of 4/7 for being a car, or of 3/7 for being a truck.

(1) Is a Bernoulli Trial of the given success rate, and (2) involves a Binomially Distribution of three Bernoulli trials of the given success rate.

> 3) What is the probability that between 17:35-17:40 a person will encounter 3 cars and 2 trucks?

The joint probability mass function for two *independent* random variables is the product of the probability mass function for each.

Comment: For the 1st part, what do you mean by: it is a bernoulli trial? Is the answer simply 4/7?